# Use enum as FK in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We have a enum `Supplier`

But now we need to also have some Domain data on that relation

So in 99.9% in the domain code we doe operations on the enum like `product.Supplier == Suppliers.FedEx`

But now we also have added `product.SupplierInfo.CanAdjustPickupTime` where `SupplierInfo` is a Entity and not just a simple enum type.

I have tried these configs

```
Property(p => p.Supplier)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasColumnName("SupplierId");

HasRequired(p => p.SupplierInfo)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.Supplier); //I have also tried casting to int doing .HasForeignKey(p => (int)p.Supplier)
```

This will fail with

> The ResultType of the specified expression is not compatible with the
>   required type. The expression ResultType is
>   'MyApp.Model.Suppliers' but the required type is
>   'Edm.Int32'.  Parameter name: keyValues[0]

Also tried

```
Property(l => l.Supplier)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasColumnName("SupplierId");

HasRequired(p => p.SupplierInfo)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("SupplierId"));
```

This will offcourse give the good old

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> SupplierId: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique.
>   Property name 'SupplierId' is already defined.

I could offcourse define SupplierId as a Property use that with `HasForeignKey` But then I need to change to `.SuppliedId == (int)Suppliers.FedEx` etc. Not really a solution.

I could also add a property enum that uses the SupplierId property as backing field, but this will not work with Expressions since it needs to use real mapped DB properties

Any ideas?

Comment: We solved the problem?

Comment: No, ugly workaround sofar. Would love to get this sorted

Comment: I also encountered this problem

Comment: Let me know if you find a solution :D

Comment: ok, if I can find :)

Comment: I guess there is then no clean solution here. Hitting the same issue.

Comment: `SupplierInfo`'s primary key can be of type `Supplier`. Just don't make it an identity column.

Answer (score 0):

I have classes:

```
public class Agreement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public AgreementStateTypeEnum AgreementStateId { get; set; }
}

public class AgreementState
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

context:

```
 public class AgreementContext :DbContext
 {
     public AgreementContext() : base("SqlConnection") { }
     public DbSet<Agreement> Agreements { get; set; }
 }
```

In method **OnModelCreating** I wrote nothing.
My enum:

```
 public enum AgreementStateTypeEnum : int
 {
        InReviewing = 1,
        Confirmed = 2,
        Rejected = 3 
 }
```

In database: in table **Agreements** I have foreign key **AgreementStateId** - it is link to table **AgreementStates**.
Everything is working. For example:

```
var temp = context.Agreements.First(x => x.AgreementStateId == AgreementStateTypeEnum.Confirmed);
```

I use enum how foreign key.

Comment: How does your Entity config look like?

Comment: In my case your Agreement class would also have a AgrementState property pointing to the AgreementState enity and its this that causes problems

Comment: @Anders, I also had virtual property. But it gives an error.

Comment: But then this is not a solution to my problem :D My problem is that I want a  enum FK with a navigation property

Comment: I have Common context for migrations. And context for model. Bounded context. CommonContext contains class with virtual property and property **int AgreementStateId**

Comment: Yes but using your example i want Agreement.AgreementState property and a Agreement.AgreementStateId which is a enum

Comment: @Anders, I understand. But, if you use **Agreement.AgreementState** is a virtual property and **Agreement.AgreementStateId** is a enum then it is not work.

Comment: @Anders, Let me know if you find a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem. (I'm using EF6, NET 4.5)
So, if you create a type Enum in your code, you couldn't create a relationship with other property virtual.

```
//This is wrong, when do you create a foreignkey using a type  enum
//Do You should remove that's code on in your class Map.
 HasRequired(p => p.SupplierInfo)
.WithMany()
.HasForeignKey(p => p.Supplier); //I have also tried casting to int doing 
.HasForeignKey(p => (int)p.Supplier)
```

If did you created a type enum it means that you don't need for a table return data throught for a join in EF.
So, the correct code it is:

```
public class MyClass{

public enum myEnumType {
FedEx,
Olther
} 

public int id {get;set;}
public myEnumType Supplier {get;set;}

}

//My class Map (using Fluent...)    
public class MyClassMap {

HasKey(t => t.Id);
Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
//The type [supplier] should be [int] in database.
Property(t => t.Supplier).HasColumnName("supplier");
//That's all, you don't need write relationship, int this case 
//Because, when the data returns, the EF will to do the conversion for you.

}
```

I hope that's useful

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to deal with this scenario is to map Supplier as a regular domain object and create a separate class of known supplier IDs.

```
public class KnownSupplierIds
{
    public const int FedEx = 1;
    public const int UPS = 2;
    // etc.
}

if (product.Supplier.SupplierId == KnownSupplierIds.Fedex) { ... };
```

When your code needs to check the supplier, it can compare the IDs; when you need additional info from the domain model you just load the Supplier. The reason I prefer using a class of constants instead of an enum is that the pattern works for string comparisons also and there's no need to cast.